# Java When I debug to the end using F5 I get the value but directly using F6 I don't in Java

Tags: java

When I debug to the end using F5 I get the value but directly using F6 I don't in Java.
For accessing a class function which contains map values by key the value doesn't come directly using F6 but comes when debug till end. what could be the reason? Please help.

Comment: Surely F5 and F6 have some context. Just because you have a thought in your head doesn't mean we have the same thought.

Comment: What IDE are you using/debugging with? Or is your program supposed to respond to these keys? Please clarify.

Comment: keyList = Funcs.listPut(keyList, "Test", tranItem.tranValue("ClaasCode")); in above line of code value of tranItem.tranValue("ClaasCode") comes when I use debugging till end I mean using F5, but directly executing the line using F6 doesn't fetches the value. Using Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly ... here a short list of the functions in the debug-mode of java:

- F5 = Step Into = Go to the next codeline; if the next line is a method, go inside of it.
- F6 = Step Over = Go to the next codeline; if next line is a method, don't go inside of it.
- F7 = Step Out = process code in the same method and stop in the invoking method.
- F8 = Reumse = continue to next breakpoint.